# SimpleJdbcCall не преобразовывает ответ в массив. Кидает ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, mapping

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class 
[Lru.yota.finservices.rs.db.model.MonthAvgServiceData; 
([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
[Lru.yota.finservices.rs.db.model.MonthAvgServiceData; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

текст ошибки такой.

метод вызова хранимой процедуры.

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(template)
                .withCatalogName(CATALOG_NAME)
                .withFunctionName("getMonthAVGServiceRegistryData")
                .declareParameters(monthAvgServiceData());
        SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("p_date", date, Types.DATE)
                .addValue("p_Service_id", serviceId, Types.BIGINT);
        List<MonthAvgServiceData> monthAvgServiceData = Arrays.asList(call.executeFunction(MonthAvgServiceData[].class, source));  // тут ошибка.
```

метод .declareParameters(monthAvgServiceData());

```
private SqlOutParameter monthAvgServiceData() {
        return new SqlOutParameter("return",
                OracleTypes.ARRAY,
                "T_MONTH_AVG_SERVICE_DATA_LIST",
                new SqlReturnStructArray<>(RecursiveBeanPropertyStructArrayMapper.newInstance(MonthAvgServiceData.class))
        );
    }
```

из самой хранимой процедуры данные возвращаются в виде Object. скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при попытке преобразовать в массив падает с ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут скорее всего тебя подводит неявный синтаксический сахар от Java. Если посмотреть внутрь реализации SimpleJdbcCall#executeFunction, то можно увидеть следующее:

[image: SimpleJdbcCall#executeFunction]

Т.е. первый параметр сам по себе не используется, а нужен как синтаксический сахар. Возможно твой компилятор заменяет

```java
List<MonthAvgServiceData> monthAvgServiceData = Arrays.asList(call.executeFunction(MonthAvgServiceData[].class, source));
```

на

```java
List<MonthAvgServiceData> monthAvgServiceData = Arrays.asList((MonthAvgServiceData[])call.executeFunction(MonthAvgServiceData[].class, source));
```

Потому ошибка и падает.

Почему возвращается `Object[]`, а не `MonthAvgServiceData[]`. Если заглянуть в [реализацию SqlReturnStructArray](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/blob/master/spring-data-oracle/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/oracle/SqlReturnStructArray.java), то можно увидеть такого рода конструкцию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А метод [List#toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) возвращает нетипизованный массив, в отличии от своего собрата позицией ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наглядно это проблема может быть показана таким падающим тестом:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        Object[] arr = new Object[]{"bla", "asd"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList((String[]) executeFunction(String[].class, arr));
    }

    public <T> T executeFunction(Class<T> returnType, Object bla) {
        return (T) bla;
    }

}
```

Результат теста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуй небольшую хитрость вида:

```java
List tmp = Arrays.asList((Object[])call.executeFunction(Object[].class, source));
List<MonthAvgServiceData> monthAvgServiceData = (List<MonthAvgServiceData>) tmp;
```